# Bash dictionary error no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make my own bash script that will check if there are any duplicated files in the given directory as an argument. I can't use any premade tools, besides shasum to check the hash of a file. Using a dictionary I want to save the filename as key and hash (generated by shasum) as value. So that I compare the results afterwards. However, if I want to try this I get the following error.

```
./duper: line 18: [./duper]=17c24ce4178f3f5283e0342835c56b64600d0ce8: No such file or directory
./duper: line 18: [./duper.backup]=f4097584a410fde440244fddd34321edd2083b99: No such file or directory
./duper: line 18: [./item.txt]=61516f2530f38ece78027250de1b6f5cc14689a5: No such file or directory
./duper: line 18: [./log.txt]=c3a2850427bb5704f94c670bd0cbab5e4303bd0f: No such file or directory
./duper: line 18: [./origin_copy.txt]=0e74dbd74c383c0985fd3627f6c35b74da18c131: No such file or directory
./duper: line 18: [./origin.txt]=0e74dbd74c383c0985fd3627f6c35b74da18c131: No such file or directory
./duper: line 18: [./origin_wrong.txt]=abfb88a05ce9fd93f98eee5b33a88991d2702529: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, I've been searching the web for some hours now. But can't seem to figure it out.

My code now:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then # Check if argument has been provided
  echo ERROR: No argument supplied!
  exit 1
elif [ ! -d $1 ]; then # Check if directory exists
  echo ERROR: Directory not found!
  exit 2
fi

declare -A arr

for i in $1/*; do
  $arr[$i]=$(shasum -a1 "$i")
done
```

Comment: The assignment should be `arr[$i]=...` -- this isn't perl, the left-hand side of an assignment is just a variable name without a type prefix, whether it's to an associative array or not.

Comment: Also, note that your earlier test should be `[ ! -d "$1" ]` with the quotes to correctly handle directory names with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` in the original `$arr[$i]=...`, making it:

```
for i in "$1"/*; do
  arr[$i]=$(shasum -a1 "$i")
done
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my problem and for your quick response! This fixed my issue.

Comment: One on-the-web resource (that's also a piece of locally-installable software) you might want to reach for in the future is is http://shellcheck.net/